# How to return how many times a timer function has run in c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

so I am writing a C# program which has a simple timer function, starting like this

```
static void TimerMethod(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
   
   //Insert function code here.
                  
 }
```

I am wondering, is there a way to return how many times the timer function has run to a string? Thanks.

Comment: Why save a count to a string variable? Wouldn't an integer type be better suited for numbers and addition?

Comment: How do you usually count? You store a number somewhere and you increment it each time. Why should this be aby different? If you want to display that somewhere, some time then you do so exactly as you would display any other number. Counting and displaying numbers are unrelated.

Comment: I have just not used a count function in c# before.

Comment: By the way, use System.Windows.Forms.Timer, not System.Timers.Timer

Answer (score 1):

Keep the count in a class level variable:

```
class YourClass{

  int _timerFireCounter = 0;


  void TimerMethod(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    _timerFireCounter++;
  }


  void HowManyTimerFiresButton_Click(object source, EventArgs e){

    MessageBox.Show($"The timer has fired {_timerFireCounter} time{(_timerFireCounter==1?"":"s")}");
  }
```

Comment: @Thanks very much! However that is only retuning that the variable is never used....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; the code has only one variable and it's written to and read from - that's "usage". Inspect closely the differences between my code and yours; I've removed `static`, for example

Comment: @CaiusJard, it depends on what timer to use. Using `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer` (which uses `System.Threading.Timer` under the hood), or using aync loop with `Task.Delay` could cause multi-threading issues with `_timerFireCounter `. I'd consider to use `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: Hence my comment on the question about using S.W.F.Timer; at the OP's level other timing methods are a bridge too far